# How to define a route to display data for a specific customer?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, routes, eloquent, crud

I am creating a CRUD web-app that can also show customers their contracts. I am trying to fetch data (contracts) for a specific customer using Laravel Eloquent and vue. I am getting an empty form. I am new to Laravel Eloquent and vue.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Contract;
use App\Models\Customer;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ContractController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the contracts.
     */
    public function index($customer_id)
    {
       return $this->show($customer_id);  
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new contract.
     */
    public function create()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created contract in storage.
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'start_date' => 'required',
            'expire_date' => 'required',
            'payment' => 'required',
            'note' => 'required',
            'created_by_user' => 'required'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified contract.
     */
    public function show($customer_id)
    {
        $contracts = Contract::where('customer_id', $customer_id)->get();
        return $contracts;
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified contract.
     */
    public function edit()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified contract in storage.
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Contract $contract)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'start_date' => 'required',
            'expire_date' => 'required',
            'payment' => 'required',
            'note' => 'required',
            'created_by_user' => 'required'
        ]);
    
        $contract->update($request->all());
    
        return $contract;
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified contract from storage.
     */
    public function destroy(Contract $contract)
    {
        $contract->delete();
        
        return response()->json(['message' => 'contract deleted successfully']);
    }


}
```

This is my file to show the contracts it is working now

```
<template>
    <div> 
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Start Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Expire Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Payment</th>
                <th scope="col">Note</th>
                <th scope="col">Created By User</th>
                <th scope="col">Actions</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="contract in contracts" :key="contract.id">
                    <td>{{ contract.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ contract.start_date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ contract.expire_date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ contract.payment }}</td>
                    <td>{{ contract.note }}</td>
                    <td>{{ contract.created_by_user }}</td>
                    <td>
                      <div class="row gap-3">
                        <router-link :to="`/contracts/${contract.id}`" class="p-2 col border btn btn-primary">View</router-link>
                        <router-link :to="`/contracts/${contract.id}/edit`" class="p-2 col border btn btn-success">Edit</router-link>
                        <button @click="deleteContract(contract.id)" type="button" class="p-2 col border btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      contracts: []
    };
  },

  async created() {
    try {
      const customer_id = this.$route.params.customer_id; // Get the customer ID from route params${customer_id}/contracts/
      const response = await axios.get(`/api/contracts/${customer_id}`);
      this.contracts = response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async deleteContract(id) {
      try {
        const customer_id = this.$route.params.customer_id;
        await axios.delete(`/api/contracts/${id}`);
        this.contracts = this.contracts.filter(contract => contract.id !== id);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Now when I try to edit the contract I don't get the data inside the form. I get an empty form.

```
<template>
 <div>
   <h2 v-if="isNewContract">Add Contract</h2>
   <h2 v-else>Edit Contract</h2>
     <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
       <div class="mb-3">
         <label for="start_date" class="form-label">Start Date:</label>
         <input class="form-control" type="date" id="start_date" v-model="contract.start_date" required />
       </div>
       <div class="mb-3">
         <label for="expire_date" class="form-label">Expire Date:</label>
         <input class="form-control" type="date" id="expire_date" v-model="contract.expire_date" required />
       </div>
       <div class="mb-3">
         <label for="payment" class="form-label">Payment</label>
         <input class="form-control" type="float" id="payment" v-model="contract.payment" required />
       </div>
       <div class="mb-3">
         <label for="note" class="form-label">Note:</label>
         <textarea class="form-control" id="note" v-model="contract.note" required></textarea>
       </div>
       <div class="mb-3">
         <label for="created_by_user" class="form-label">Created By User:</label>
         <input class="form-control" type="text" id="created_by_user" v-model="contract.created_by_user" required />
       </div>
   
       <button type="submit" v-if="isNewContract" class="btn btn-primary">Add Contract</button>
       <button type="submit" v-else class="btn btn-primary">Update Contract</button>
       
     </form>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
 data() {
   return {
     contract: {
       start_date: '',
       expire_date: '',
       payment: 0,
       note: '',
       created_by_user: ''
     }
   }
 },
 computed: {
     isNewContract() {
     return !this.$route.path.includes('edit');
   }
 },
 async created() {
   if (!this.isNewContract) {
     const response = await axios.get(`/api/contracts/${this.$route.params.id}`);
     this.contract = response.data;
   }
 },
 methods: {
   async submitForm() {
     try {
       if (this.isNewContract) {
         await axios.post('/api/contracts', this.contract);
       } else {
         await axios.put(`/api/contracts/${this.$route.params.id}`, this.contract);
       }
       this.$router.push('/');
     } catch (error) {
       console.error(error);
     }
   }
 }
}
</script>
```

This is the Link to access the contracts

```
      { path: '/contracts/:customer_id', component: ContractList },
       { path: '/contracts/create', component: ContractForm },
       { path: '/contracts/:id', component: Contract },
       { path: '/contracts/:id/edit', component: ContractForm },
```

//This is my the route for the contracts in api.php
//Route::resource('contracts', ContractController::class);

Comment: "_I keep getting error messages._" Would you mind sharing those error messages or do you want us to guess?

Comment: GET
http://api/customers/1/contracts
[HTTP/1 404 Not Found 248ms]

Comment: Show your route which is used in api.php and component axios call. Because it seems like you have got problem with your route.

Comment: Route::resource('contracts', ContractController::class);

Comment: const customer_id = this.$route.params.customer_id; 
   const response = await axios.get(`/api/${customer_id}/contracts`);

Comment: I am getting an error in here                                                                                   
 async created() {
    try {
    const customer_id = this.$route.params.$customer_id; 
      const response = await axios.get(`/api/${customer_id}/contracts`);
      this.contracts = response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

Comment: Keep updating your original question. Feel free to show your entire route including the route group with your api prefix. Resource route with the route you're using is not going to work that way